# EEEPC 701 4G will not take a new Distro

Tags: boot, xubuntu, lubuntu, disk-usage, eeepc

I lost the use of three machines in the great late **November update** (see my other threads) I have tried all the obvious things with no luck to try to get these to boot up.

EEEPC – I was running Peppermint Three on this – mainly so I could use FoxtrotGPS for navigation. – As it was not used with much data I decided to do a re-install. I tried Peppermint 7, Peppermint 6, Xubuntu (including the non graphic install) Lubuntu and Peppermint 3 all without sucsess.

Whenever I try a new distro, the live USB works fine (Created with Unetbootin) but when I try to install I get either a blank screen or a partial install (desktop with no Icons) – what I have also had is a message that I need 3.6?G of free space and this prompted me to look at my hard disk.

I booted from a live USB and ran fdisk-l

This shows;

`device     boot        blocks      System
/dev/sda1   *       3391488 Linux
/dev/sda2           513025  Extended
/dev/sda1           513024  Linux swap / Solaris`
[image]

Am I right in assuming I need to totally wipe the hard disk to make space to install Lubuntu?
If so how can I do this?
Use a live USB with a distro or use something like Gparted?
Or should I give up due to small drive space n this machine?

Many thanks.

Update - I read that Unetbootin from the Ubuntu repository had issues so I reinstalled from another PPA; the same thing happens; it freezes; tried terminal tty1 ran apt-get install lubuntu-core and sudo apt-get update I get the following outputs[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 4 GB is 'not enough' for an installed system

I think the installer checks for the available drive space, and it complains, when it is not enough. And 4 GB is not enough for an installed system (according to the setting).

### Persistent live system

4 GB is plenty for a persistent live system, because most of the system is stored in a compressed 'squashfs' file. So if you install Lubuntu as a persistent live system into your 4 GB drive, there will be more space for application programs and personal data.

You can use mkusb to create a persistent live system.

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

A persistent live system is sensitive, so it is important to backup the 'persistent' data, which is stored in the casper-rw partition. There are scripts for it, and with only 4 GB inside, you should direct the backup to an external drive (pendrive or better, a USB hard disk drive).

It is also possible to run a persistent live system in the eeePC from a fast USB 3 pendrive with 16 or 32 GB.

**Edit:** {Solution: a persistent live system on an **SD card** using the built in card slot.}

See this link,

[FromUSBStick#Prerequisites](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Prerequisites)

### Minimal Lubuntu from Ubuntu mini.iso

If you are not happy with a persistent live system, you can start from the Ubuntu [mini.iso](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/netboot/), and install a minimal system. During the installation, or afterwards, you can install Lubuntu (the meta-package lubuntu-desktop)

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

and get Lubuntu into the 4 GB drive. You might prefer Lubuntu Core, and add only the necessary program packages to save drive space,

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-core
```

See this link for more details,

[Lubuntu/Documentation/MinimalInstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/MinimalInstall)

Comment: Thank Sudodus; I think I will try the minimal install - I had no success with the Xubuntu minimal but I will give it another go.still don't get how Peppermint 3 used to fit on this machine - and now it no longer does

Comment: Linux is growing all the time. Part of the reason is that drivers are added for new hardware and web browsers are made able to read new web pages. Part of the reason is probably that it is getting 'bloated' in general.

Comment: Hi - it is still not working even with a tiny install - now puts me straight into TTY1 on boot what ever I do.

Comment: Please describe what you did! - Did you install lubuntu-core?

Comment: Hi, yes I tried to install the mini-iso via unetbootin on a USB; installed core and tried to install Lubuntu-core;                                                             'sudo -i
apt-get install lubuntu-core' loads of failed packages
'apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoclean
rm /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb' no such file...
now hangs at /dev/sda1: clean, 57860/212160 files, 297357/847872 blocks

Comment: What happened, when you tried to install Lubuntu Core? Was there some error output? What happened after reboot? The computer *should* boot into a graphical session.

Comment: I have seen that the Unetbootin version in the Ubuntu repositories is not up to date so I am re-installing details;
[https://launchpad.net/~gezakovacs/+archive/ubuntu/ppa]

'sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa'
'sudo apt-get update'
'sudo apt-get install unetbootin'

Comment: You are right about Unetbootin. There is a bug report about it, but nothing has happened yet. You can use another tool to install the iso file to a USB boot drive, for example mkusb. It works with all current Ubuntu versions. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb

Comment: I tried the minimal install and many small Linux distros without success. Booting from a Maverick CD worked failed.  I think that the SSD has bad sectors.
MKUSB is a superb and it makes creating a persistent drive very easy.
I installed a Peppermint 7 on a SD card using the built in card slot - and was gratified that after shutdown it remembered the wireless network password and FoxtrotGPS added by Synaptic was there after a re-boot. hopefully this will give those with old Asus EEEpc 2 or 4Gs a new lease of life without resorting to hardware hack to upgrade the hard-wired SSD.

Comment: Congratulations and thanks for sharing your solution :-) If you wish you can 'reply to your own question' and mark it as the 'best answer'.

Comment: I have marked your answer as the solution - What a brilliant and elegant hack for old hardware! With fast SD cards getting cheaper all the time this will be a life line for old machines - with the added plus I can use a portable persistent distro on other machines. Kudos to you sudodus!